# How do you slice or split a string on a certain character in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

If I had a string like the one below how would I split it at every 3rd character or any other specified character?

```
b = "123456789"
```

The result would be this:

```
b = ["123","456","789"]
```

I've tried using these method: `b.split("").each_slice(3).to_a`

But it results in this : `[["1", "2", "3"], ["4", "5", "6"], ["7", "8", "9"]]`

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 6):

I'd use:

```
b = "123456789"
b.scan(/.{3}/) # => ["123", "456", "789"]
```

---

If the OP's sample were to be a different length, or it had an embedded "\n", a simple modification works:

```
b = "123456789"
b.scan(/.{1,3}/) # => ["123", "456", "789"]
b[0..-2].scan(/.{1,3}/) # => ["123", "456", "78"]
"#{ b }\n#{ b }".scan(/.{1,3}/) # => ["123", "456", "789", "123", "456", "789"]
```

Now, if there is an embedded "\n" NOT on an even "3" boundary, it breaks:

```
"#{ b[0..-2] }\n#{ b }".scan(/.{1,3}/) # => ["123", "456", "78", "123", "456", "789"]
```

but that is getting rather far afield from the OP's simple specification, and can be fixed by stripping the new-line(s) first:

```
"#{ b[0..-2] }\n#{ b }".delete("\n").scan(/.{1,3}/) # => ["123", "456", "781", "234", "567", "89"]
```

Comment: Right. If I understand requirements correctly, this is a better answer

Comment: +1 Nice and elegant. Doesn't work if `b.length % 3 != 0`, but this does: `b.scan(/..?.?/)`

Comment: A fix to iamnotmaynard's issue would be `b.scan(/.{,3}/)`.

Comment: "Won't work if you have "\n" in the string." NONE of the solutions would work correctly with embedded new-lines as-is. We work to the specs given by the OP.

Comment: I meant, it won't make 3 character strings that would contain \n in them. I didn't mean to skip them. New line is not matches by /./.

Comment: New line is matched if the regex uses the multiline option `m`: `"#{ b[0..-2] }\n#{ b }".scan(/.{1,3}/m) # => ["123", "456", "78\n", "123", "456", "789"]`. But then, yes, that's more an academic exercise than the solution OP is looking for.

Answer (score 5):

You almost made it.

```
b = "123456789"
b.split("").each_slice(3).map(&:join) # => ["123", "456", "789"]
```

Answer (score 5):

```
b = "123456789"
b.chars.each_slice(3).map(&:join)
# => ["123", "456", "789"]
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way:

```
my_s, my_a = '123456789', []
my_a << my_s.slice!(0..2) until my_s.empty?
p my_a # => ["123", "456", "789"]
```

Comment: Nice.  Could use `shift(3)` in place of `slice!(0..2)`.

Comment: I am using slice! on a atring. String is not an enumerable anymore (since 1.9 if I remember correctly).

Comment: hirolau, `shift(3)` works fine with v2.0.  I don't understand what that has to do with 'enumerable'.  Could you please explain?

Comment: I thought shift was a methods for enumerable, but it appears it is only for arrays. Strings do no have the shift method. String.methods.index(:shift) in 2.0 gives me nil. Are you sure you are not using any extension? http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html does not include any :shift-method.

Comment: Thanks, hirolau.  I copied your code, substituted `shift(3)` for `slice!(0..2)`, ran it, saw `p my_a # => ["123", "456", "789"]`, and assumed it ran fine.  What I saw, in my haste, was the last line of your code (not the error message)!  PS I suggest you include @name in your reply so @name will know you've replied.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers, if you want to split on an arbitrary set of characters (this answer doesn't cover every third character because there's more than enough answers on that already) and decide *where* the splitting characters go, you can also use `split` like so:

```
# Split and include splitting character in next slice
"123456789".split(/(?=[36])/)     # => ["12", "345", "6789"]

# Split and include splitting character in slice
"123456789".split(/(?<=[36])/)    # => ["123", "456", "789"]

# Split and exclude character from slices
"123456789".split(/[36]/)         # => ["12", "45", "789"]
```

Bear in mind that this *does* use regular expressions and, for your purposes, it may be better to find a way to split the string using a less over-the-top route (see detunized's answer, which is fairly succinct and a reasonable way to handle this). Depending on the complexity of the string being split, what you're splitting on, what to do with splitting characters/phrases/etc., and so on, your approach might change.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't create temporary array, works for any set and number of characters and doesn't use slow regular expressions. Not as elegant though.

```
s = "1234567"
(0...s.size / 3).map { |i| s[i * 3, 3] }
# => ["123", "456", "7"]
```

**Benchmark:**

```
require "benchmark"

N = 100000

Benchmark.bm do |x|
    b = "123456789"
    x.report { N.times { (0...b.size / 3).map { |i| b[i * 3, 3] } } }
    x.report { N.times { b.scan(/.{3}/) } }
    x.report { N.times { b.chars.each_slice(3).map(&:join) } }
    x.report { N.times { b.split("").each_slice(3).map(&:join) } }
end
```

Results:

```
$ ruby split3.rb
       user     system      total        real
   0.080000   0.000000   0.080000 (  0.079944)
   0.130000   0.000000   0.130000 (  0.127715)
   0.300000   0.000000   0.300000 (  0.299186)
   0.640000   0.000000   0.640000 (  0.641817)
```

I tried to change the order of the lines to see if there's any strange side effects. The results are consistent. The order doesn't matter.

Comment: `s = "12\n3456\n7";
(0...s.size / 3).map { |i| s[i * 3, 3] } # => ["12\n", "345", "6\n7"]`.

Comment: @the Tin Man, that's correct, isn't it? Three characters in each.